# Is there a way to reorganize a CSV file by deleting and adding CRLFs?

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to clean a csv file that contains the following records:

[image: image of the data viewed in Notepad++]

The 'NULNUL's are written as \x00\x00 in notepad ++ and are positioned at the end of each record.

But the CRLFs in the column 'text_field' are creating records with text in the first field and missing values in the rest of the columns.

I want to delete the current the CRLFs and then replace the NULNULs with CRLFs.
I tried the following:

'''

```
for filename in os.listdir('C:\Users\Username\Desktop\file.csv'):

    print("Start")

    if filename.endswith('.csv'):

            with open(os.path.join('C:\Users\Username\Desktop\other_file.csv', filename), "r", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as file:
                data = re.sub("\r\n", "", file.read(),flags=re.MULTILINE)
                data = file.read().replace('\x00\x00', '\r\n')
                print("replacing " + filename + " succeeded !")

            with open(os.path.join(':\Users\Username\Desktop\other_file.csv', filename), "w", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as file:
                file.write(data)
                file.close()
```

'''

This approaches did not work, any tips that might help me out?
much appreciated!

Comment: `.. did not work` =- what went wrong?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). [Why not upload images of code on SO  ...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).  [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755).

Comment: All of what you are looking to accomplish can be done simply in NPP itself.

Answer (score 0):

With these two lines

```
            data = re.sub("\r\n", "", file.read(),flags=re.MULTILINE)
            data = file.read().replace('\x00\x00', '\r\n')
```

- First you read the file replace some stuff and assign the result to `data`.
- Second you read the file replace some stuff and assign the result to `data`.

  - You lost the changes you made in the first line.
  - After the first read the file is at the end so file.read() returns an empty string.

Assuming the first line *works* - the second line should be

```
            data = data.replace('\x00\x00', '\r\n')
```